# Speed of OpenGL draw call

Tags: opengl

I want to build a lightning with a texture in OpenGL. For this I have to draw some triangles which are conected in one X|Y point, so a triangle starts where the last ends. That's why I want to draw the rectangles successively and now it comes to my question:

Which draw call is longer? The first has 6 points to draw. In the second I call the function two times with 3 points both times.

```
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 6);  // Both recatangles

/or this here
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 3);  // One rectangle
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 3);  // One rectangle
```

Is it much faster to call the first or does not matter?

EDIT: My function to generate random points which is called every frame:

```
public void update()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < STEPS; i += 3)
    {
        float rnd = random(); // creates random number

        if(points[i] + rnd < startX + 5 && points[i] + rnd > startX - 5)
        {
            points[i] += rnd;
        }
    }

    vertexBuffer.clear();   
    vertexBuffer.put(points);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);
}
```

Is that bad for the performance or how can I do it better?

Comment: One call will be cheaper. Not significantly for just two, but if you start drawing many primitives it'll pay off.

Comment: That is not a real question in its current form. Why not just profile it?

Comment: Thew fewer API calls the better. There is no real benefit to drawing these things separately, it only adds additional overhead. Too many API calls that do little to no work will actually cause your limiting factor to shift from CPU/GPU power to something silly like API overhead. In the old days there used to be a 1:1 mapping between API calls and vertices / polygons, but these days the API has evolved into something that allows you to do multiple operations in a single call - you ***need*** to take advantage of the modern design to get good performance.

Comment: okay thanks for that. And what about manipulate the vertex points? I added an `update function` to the question which I call every frame to generate a random lightning. I change the vertecies points and draw the new generated points whith a function from above. Is that bad for the performance or how can I do it better?

Comment: The better way to do this is to use shaders. You can probably use a noise function on some varying property (e.g. time) to generate sufficiently "random" vertex properties. But if you're not up to that level yet, then you can keep doing it the way you are... just remember to try and do this in a way where you only have to call `glBufferData (...)` or `glBufferSubData (...)` one time, as discussed in my previous comment - do more with less.